# OrientDB date datetime format

Tags: date, datetime, format, orientdb

I have a question about Format in OrientDB DATE and DATETIME.

For each format change, I know what is possible using the following. And I also confirmed using it.

```
ALTER DATABASE DATEFORMAT "yyyy/MM/dd"

ALTER DATABASE DATETIMEFORMAT "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
```

However, data obtained from OrientDB is expired in conformity with dateformat regarding date.

For example, if you get with the above change the result is like this.

```
"DATE": "2018/01/24 00:00:00"

"DATETIME": "2018/01/24 12:00:00"
```

I want you to come out as follows.

```
"DATE": "2018/01/24",

"DATETIME": "2018/01/24 12:00:00"
```

Can I change the output from each Orient DB?

Is it specifications based on DATETIME?

I am sorry in poor English, but I'd appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: What version are you using? Thx

Comment: I'm using OrientDB Server v2.2.25

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the date as follow:

```
"DATE": "2018/01/24",
```

so, avoiding 00:00:00, you can perform this query:

```
select <your-property>.format("yyyy/MM/dd") from <your-class>
```

this is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards